# Jade not rendering variable to view

Tags: angularjs, express, pug, mean

I'm going through the "Building Angular and Node.js Apps with the MEAN stack" course at pluralSight.  I'm fairly new to the MEAN stack, specifically the back end so please forgive me if i'm being vague.  So here is what I have going on... I'm trying to get my message object from Mongodb to show up using jade. I'm not getting any kind of errors and I have actually started over from the beginning of the video just to make sure I didn't miss something the first time.  I can provide specific details if you'd like.  Any idea's on why this isn't working would be greatly appreciated.

**index.js**

```
var messageSchema = mongoose.Schema({message: String});
var Message = mongoose.model('Message', messageSchema);
var mongoMessage;
Message.findOne().exec(function(err, messageDoc) {
    mongoMessage = messageDoc.message; //this is where i'm grabbing the data from mongodb and assigning it to this variable, right? 
});


app.get('/partials/:partialPath', function(req, res) {
    res.render("partials/" + req.params.partialPath);
});

app.get('*', function(req, res) { 
    res.render('index', { //
        mongoMessage: mongoMessage //this is the variable that is not showing
    });
});
```

**index.jade**

```
extends ../includes/layout

block main-content
section.content
    div(ng-view)
h2= mongoMessage //this variable is not showing in the browser
```

**dependencies**

```
"dependencies": {
"body-parser": "^1.15.0",
"bower": "^1.7.7",
"express": "^4.13.4",
"jade": "^1.11.0",
"mongoose": "^4.4.10",
"morgan": "^1.7.0",
"stylus": "^0.54.2"
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is showing because jade is based on indentation. You need to put the tags inside of your `block main-content` like this:

```
block main-content
  section.content
    div(ng-view)
  h2= mongoMessage //this variable is not showing in the browser
```

And I am not sure how your code is structured, but if you want your h2 inside of the div you need to indent that as well:

```
 block main-content
    section.content
      div(ng-view)
        h2= mongoMessage //this variable is not showing in the browser
```

Comment: That did the trick:) Thank you a ton kind stranger!!!  I should probably read up on Jade a bit more if i'm going to try and use it.

Comment: No problem. If it helped you I'd appreciate an upvote or an accept of the answer.